# Problem with LayoutInflater Android

Tags: android

So here is my code in View.

```
public class TheView extends View {
..
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    ....
     LayoutInflater inflater = this.game.getLayoutInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.status, null);
    ....
    }
}
```

And here is the xml file code which is named as "status.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:title="@string/app_name"/>
</menu>
```

"TheView" is called from another activity. And in the View i have drawn a canvas and have painted some graphics on top of it. I need to get a inflated menu on top of that. But when i try it with the given code it gives the following error

```
04-10 20:05:27.090: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2208): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 20:05:27.090: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2208): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class menu
04-10 20:05:27.090: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2208):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-10 20:05:27.090: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2208):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
04-10 20:05:27.090: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2208):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `MenuInflater` to inflate a menu. And if you want to inflate a layout then do not use `menu` tag.

Comment: I changed into MenuInflater and moved the xml into new folder named as menu as well. And i get an new error.04-10 20:37:08.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3127): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 20:37:08.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3127): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 20:37:08.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3127):     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:310)
04-10 20:37:08.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3127):     at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:154)
04-10 20:37:08.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3127):     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.jav

Comment: Seems that you pass `null` in the second argument.

Comment: Try reading this documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: I agree with you. But my problem is what else i can pass there. Because i'm calling the method from a "View" class. It does not have any menu passing methods. Can you give any tip. Any way thank you for the previous advice

Comment: I don't undersand what you're trying to do. Maybe if you describe the problem you're solving, I'll be able to help you. If you really want to show a menu from a view, then create a listener interface in a view and subscribe this listener from an activity. In the handler call `openContextMenu(View)` passing the view as an argument. The view must be registered for showing context menu (see `Activity.registeredForContextMenu(View)`).

Comment: But I think that's not a good idea to show a menu without pressing hardware menu button. Users usually do not expect such behavior, so maybe you should choose another solution.